# Wearable watchface not installed on LG G Watch

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to develop a WatchFace app.
Everything works good while I install a wearable module on the watch directly by launching the wearable configuration. But for it to be able to be installed from the Play Store I need to package handheld (mobile) module with dependency to the wearable module. Here is my build.gradle of the modile module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mvl.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

wearApp project(':wear') this line should include the wearable APK file into handheld APK (into res/raw/ directory of the APK archive). And it actually does. But when I install the mobile APK on my Sony Xperia Z Ultra (connected to the LG G Watch) it does not install the wearable application on the watch.
I've checked it with `adb shell pm list packages` command for the LG G Watch. My application's package is not in the list.
Here is the AndroidManifest.xml of my wear module:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mvl.myapplication" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:allowEmbedded="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview"
                android:resource="@drawable/chooser_bg"/>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Also I sign mobile (and as a dependancy - wearable) module with release key, not debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved the problem with a combination of few changes, not sure which actually helped:
Declared same dependencies in the handheld(mobile) manifest;

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Cleaned the project;
Deleted all generated .apk files.